# Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>

Tags: macros, tags

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> C:\Users\Rahul.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4ccff20ef7c231e6ca175cf84e24aa03\transformed\material-1.9.0\res\values\values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.

I am getting the above error when I am trying to build the apk

I have tried to upgrade gradle but its still showing the same problem and "implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'" also added this code in build.gradle its still not working.